# Reducing the number of iNodes used by .html pages

Tags: web-hosting

I don't know if i'm in the right section of the stackexchange here, but it seemed to me to be a good place to ask my question.

I have a "website" which is based about developing Autodesk Inventor applications. To properly discuss and reference the subject I have the Autodesk Inventor API `.chm` file decompiled to `.html` pages. To these pages I create links so others can see what objects/methods are used..

My problem now is, as my website is still small and low low budget, decompoling the `.chm` file to `.html` files has left me with 22.806 files and my `iNodes`or files limit is only 20.000. What can I do to reduce the number of files? is there a way compile them into a more compact file?

Comment: A CHM file is composed of a collection of HTML files.  It is typically all the help documents for a single program.   It is typically used by Windows for help functionality.   (Adding a bit of background because I had to look it up.)

Comment: 20,000 HTML files for documentation about a single program seems like a lot to me.  It seems plausible to me that many of them don't have content, but might be indexes or frames.   Without a file list, I'm not sure I can be of much help though.

Comment: Well +20.000 actually and it's about the program its API and how to interact with it's Object oriented programming. For example there is a object html page called line. A line has 10 properties and 3 methods and 1 sample these all have their own html page so thats 15 pages for the line object. I could compile a list but then again it would be +20.000. If this could help I will generate it. Web help pages are page by page uploaded or is there a compiled "tool" also like CHM?

Comment: You could import the data into a database and build something to serve it, but that sounds like a bigger project.

Answer (score 1):

**Combine the HTML pages**

Instead of running hundreds of individual HTML pages, you can instead run one PHP page that serves multiple HTML pages which would be good if you want to serve guests with very old browsers, or you could use javascript if the functionality of each page is basic enough.

In PHP you can use this code to start:

```
<?php
$wantedpage=$_GET['Page'];
if ($wantedpage=="toys"){
?>
Welcome to the page about baby cribs and other toys.
<?php
}
if ($wantedpage=="cats"){
?>
Welcome to the page about kitty cats
<?php
}
if ($wantedpage=="cars"){
?>
Welcome to the page about race cars
<?php
}
?>
```

Then a guest can call your PHP file up and add a `?page=x` to the end of the URL where x is the page wanted. In my example, if x is "cars" then "Welcome to the page about race cars" will be displayed on my screen. So far, my file will save you from creating three individual html pages.

In Javascript, you can do this:

```
<script>
function processbox(){
document.getElementById('box').innerHTML="You clicked the box";
}
</script>
<p>Click on the box to continue.</p>
<div ID="box" onclick="processbox();" style="border: 3px solid black;width:200px;height:200px">
click me
</div>
```

I haven't tested the javascript but when you click the box, "click me" will change to "You clicked the box" without requesting another page load, thereby saving you one file.

It really all depends on your audience, but learning a server-side programming language and using it to produce the appropriate text based on the parameters the user passes in is the best way to go.